# React Semantic UI component not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I used `create-react-app` to initialize my app. Then I did `npm install semantic-ui-react --save` to install the package.

I want to create this `Grid` example from https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid#grid-example-divided-number:

[image]

I created a file called `Grid.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const GridExample = () => (
  <Grid columns={3} divided>
    <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>

    <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
  </Grid>
)

export default GridExample
```

Then in `App.js` I imported `GridExample`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GridExample from './Grid'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>

        <GridExample />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

However, when the web page loads the `<p>` elements are stacked on top of each other - as if `6X1` instead of the intended `2X3`

Why is the `Grid` not being rendered properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are forgetting to add the CSS file.

According to the docs:

> This is the quickest way to get started with Semantic UI React. You won't be able to use custom themes with this method.
>
> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css"></link>`

See https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#css for more options on how to reference it